# Postback of a dynamic create button not always executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, postbackurl

I have an ASP page with a table containing always different rows, dynamically loaded from a MSSQL DB. In each row of the table I have created a `Button`, called Details, that is dynamically created during the writing of the table. This Details button is added with the following code:

```
Button detailsButton = new Button();
detailsButton.Height = new Unit("18px");
detailsButton.Width = new Unit("65px");
detailsButton.Text = "Details";
detailsButton.ID = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();

detailsButton.PostBackUrl = "~\\DetailsPage.aspx?selectedSignalling=" +  detailsButton.ID;
//detailsButton.Click += detailsAgencyButton_Click;
//detailsButton.OnClientClick = "return true;";

table1cell4.Controls.Add(detailsButton);
table1row.Cells.Add(table1cell4);
```

The intention is to redirect the client towards the Postback URL when one button is pressed on a row. The Postback URL is dynamically created for each button, associating to each of them the ID of the item that the user would choose to display the details.

While this works fine on the my development environment, that is running IIS 7.5, this is not always working on the production environment, that runs IIS 6.0 and that cannot be updated. On IIS 6.0, some clients does not notice any problem, while others are not able to display the details page, but, when clicking on the Details button, the postback URL is not loaded and instead there is only the reload of the current page.

I have tried to change many settings (set the `detailsButton.Click`, set the `OnClientClick` to "`return true;`"), but without luck. I have only noticed that adding the:

```
detailsButton.OnClientClick = "return true;";
```

instruction, the redirect does not work in IIS 7.5 too. So it seems to me that when `OnClientClick` returns something (true/false), the PostBack is not activated, while some of the clients probably does not return any `OnClientClick` and the PostBack is activated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using javascript redirect associated to onClientClick event and returning false on the same event. This prevents the server to be invoked and the client redirects towards the new page without refreshing the old page.

```
detailsButton.OnClientClick = "windows.open(' new_page.aspx ', '_self'); return false;";
```